# How to test the identity and an associativity constraints of a java-8 custom Collector

Tags: java, java-stream

I have written a custom Collector for Java 8. Its aggregator is a Map containing a pair of lists:

```
    @Override
    public Supplier<Map<Boolean, List<Object>>> supplier() {
        return () -> {
            Map<Boolean, List<Object>> map = new HashMap<>(2);
            map.put(false, new ArrayList<>());
            map.put(true, new ArrayList<>());
            return map;
        };
    }
```

so I think its combiner is this:

```
    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Map<Boolean, List<Object>>> combiner() {
        return (a, b) -> {
            a.get(false).addAll(b.get(false));
            a.get(true).addAll(b.get(true));
            return a;
        };
    }
```

I would like to test the Collector to make sure that if and when it processes a stream in parallel, the result is correct.

How can I write a unit test that exercises this?

Of course I can write a test that calls the `combiner` directly, but that's not what I want. I want evidence it works in the context of collecting.

The Javadoc for `Collector` says:

> To ensure that sequential and parallel executions produce equivalent results, the collector functions must satisfy an identity and an associativity constraints.

Could I achieve confidence in my Collector by testing these constraints? How?

Comment: Depends on your `Stream` really. It's up to the `Spliterator` to decide how to dice up the data for different threads. So, if you implement a `Spliterator` that has a `trySplit` that splits the data then you can "force" execution in parallel. Note however, that it's almost impossible to verify the correct functioning of parallel code with testing.

Comment: On another note, how is your collector different to [`Collectors.partitioningBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-)?

Comment: @BoristheSpider it's very similar, but the input type is an `Either<L,R>` which is collected into a type containing a `List<L>` and a `List<R>`.

Comment: @slim I wish this question got a little bit more attention and as such I think the title of it should really be : "how to test the identity and an associativity constraints of a java-8 custom collector", because ultimately that's what you want. From the docs: `To ensure that sequential and parallel executions produce equivalent results, the collector functions must satisfy an identity and an associativity constraints.`

Comment: wondering how the base collectors were tested. where is the test code of Java itself?

Comment: @Roland that was exactly my thought. The same thing would be about some lock free algorithm, let's say like `LongAdder`

Comment: HashMap is not thread-safe so you might have problems with parallel streams.

Comment: @Alastair as I understand it, the accumulator does not need to be thread-safe. Each thread will get a separate accumulator. I'm willing to be corrected though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With thanks to both answerers, who sent me down what I think is the right path.

It's of course possible to create a parallel stream to exercise the `Collector` as a whole:

```
T result = myList.stream().parallel().collect(myCollector);
```

But you can't guarantee the boundaries on which it will split, not even that it will split at all; short of perhaps writing a custom `Spliterator`.

Therefore testing the contract seems like the way to go. Trust `Stream.collect()` to do the right thing given a `Collector` that works. It's common practice to not test "provided" libraries.

---

The `Collector` JavaDoc defines the constraints, and even provides code describing the associativity constraint. We can pull this code into a testing class that's usable in the real world:

```
public class CollectorTester<T, A, R> {

    private final Supplier<A> supplier;
    private final BiConsumer<A, T> accumulator;
    private final Function<A, R> finisher;
    private final BinaryOperator<A> combiner;

    public CollectorTester(Collector<T, A, R> collector) {
        this.supplier = collector.supplier();
        this.accumulator = collector.accumulator();
        this.combiner = collector.combiner();
        this.finisher = collector.finisher();
    }

    // Tests that an accumulator resulting from the inputs supplied
    // meets the identity constraint
    public void testIdentity(T... ts) {
        A a = supplier.get();
        Arrays.stream(ts).filter(t -> t != null).forEach(
            t -> accumulator.accept(a, t)
        );

        assertThat(combiner.apply(a, supplier.get()), equalTo(a));
    }

    // Tests that the combiner meets the associativity constraint
    // for the two inputs supplied
    // (This is verbatim from the Collector JavaDoc)
    // This test might be too strict for UNORDERED collectors
    public void testAssociativity(T t1, T t2) {
        A a1 = supplier.get();
        accumulator.accept(a1, t1);
        accumulator.accept(a1, t2);
        R r1 = finisher.apply(a1); // result without splitting

        A a2 = supplier.get();
        accumulator.accept(a2, t1);
        A a3 = supplier.get();
        accumulator.accept(a3, t2);
        R r2 = finisher.apply(combiner.apply(a2, a3)); // result with splitting

        assertThat(r1, equalTo(r2));
    }

}
```

What remains is to test this with a sufficient range of inputs. One way to achieve this is with JUnit 4's `Theories` runner. For example, to test `Collectors.joining()`:

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class MaxCollectorTest {

    private final Collector<CharSequence, ?, String> coll = Collectors.joining();
    private final CollectorTester<CharSequence, ?, String> tester = new CollectorTester<>(coll);

    @DataPoints
    public static String[] datapoints() {
        return new String[] { null, "A", "rose", "by", "any", "other", "name" };
    }

    @Theory
    public void testAssociativity(String t1, String t2) {
        assumeThat(t1, notNullValue());
        assumeThat(t2, notNullValue());
        tester.testAssociativity(t1, t2);
    }

    @Theory
    public void testIdentity(String t1, String t2, String t3) {
        tester.testIdentity(t1, t2, t2);
    }
}
```

(I find it pleasing that my test code doesn't need to know the type of `Collectors.joining()`'s accumulator (which is not declared by the API) for this test to work)

---

Note that this *only* tests the associativity and identity constraints -- you also need to test the domain logic of your collector. It's probably safest to achieve this through a balanced mixture of checking the result of a `collect()` and directly calling the `Collector`'s methods.

Answer (score 3):

You are basically asking if [`List.addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) is associative. Because the identity is trivially solved by [`Object.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), which each standard collection (that you use) guarantees to follow.

## Associativity

Associativity means the following:

> Within an expression containing two or more occurrences in a row of the same associative operator, the order in which the operations are performed does not matter as long as the sequence of the operands is not changed. That is, rearranging the parentheses in such an expression will not change its value. Consider the following equations:
>
> ```
> (2 + 3) + 4 = 2 + (3 + 4) = 9
> 2 × (3 × 4) = (2 × 3) × 4 = 24
> ```
>
> -- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property)

**Yes `List.addAll`s is associative.**

Let's show it by example:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
  // Give addAll an operator look.
  static <T> List<T> myAddAll(List<T> left, List<T> right) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(left);
    result.addAll(right);
    return result;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    List<Integer> b = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6);
    List<Integer> c = Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9);

    // Combine a and b first, then combine the result with c.
    System.out.println(myAddAll(myAddAll(a, b), c)); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

    // Combine b and c first, then combine a with the result.
    System.out.println(myAddAll(a, myAddAll(b, c))); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  }
}
```

## Testing

The contract for `Collector` is exactly what you wrote: make sure that the combiner has both the *identity* and the *associativity* properties. If you follow that, you won't get any issue (make sure you hint that your [`Spliterator` is `ORDERED`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#ORDERED) if required, of course).

The test then boils down to simply test that your combiner has those two properties. The *identity* part is guaranteed by equals, the *associativity* part is handled by writing a test similar to the code above. It boils down to that because, as @mrmcgreg said in the comments, you shouldn't test the framework itself: that's the Java authors' responsibility. If you would encounter any trouble after having proved your combiner fulfills the two properties, you should probably file a bug to Java.

Comment: Correct answer. I removed mine, probably a bit tired if I confusing associativity and commutativity :/. Time for a coffee :)

Comment: No worries, it happens ;-)

Comment: Thanks - but the other part of the question is about proving in unit tests that the combiner works in the context of collecting. Would you say that the only way to directly exercise the function returned by `combiner()` to see that it fulfils its contract?

Comment: @slim Well, that boils down to indeed testing if the combiner indeed fulfills its contract. Then, you have to make sure to keep your stream `ORDERED`, so that the parallelism is appropriately done (usually by cutting consecutive chunks, processing them sequentially in each thread and combining them afterwards). This is why I allowed myself to say that your question is basically asking if `addAll` is associative.

Comment: @slim I think the point of using a framework like this to not worry about the execution details if you've fulfilled the required contracts. Making sure that things work 'in the context of collecting' would be the job of the framework authors.

Answer (score 2):

Olivier answered the associativity/identity part.

Regarding tests, you can either cook up your own test cases that hopefully cover all corner cases, or try out property based testing ala Haskell [QuickCheck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickCheck) (Java has [QuickTheories](https://github.com/ncredinburgh/QuickTheories), for example).

What this will do is generate a bunch of random objects and see if the properties you declare hold for all of them when you apply your operator. A steeper learning curve to get into, but worth the effort afterwards :)

Comment: Thank you. JUnit 4 has `import org.junit.experimental.theories.Theories` built-in, and I've used it with some success. Could well be worth trying on this problem, or seeing what QuickTheories adds.